# If a toy car moves down a ramp, would the speed be constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

When it moves down a declining ramp, would the speed of the toy car be constant? If not, what would the distance/time graph look like? (distance as in the distance the car moved)

Comment: Depends. What's the angle of the ramp? Incline or decline? Starting velocity? Height of the ramp? This question needs a lot more details

Comment: If the speed were constant (no acceleration at all), this means that if it were stationary, it would remain stationary.  This isn't the case though, so there must be a nonzero acceleration.  This agrees with everyday intuition (imagine going down a hill on a bicycle without peddling).

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the ramp is a decline (I think it is, given "moving down a ramp").

Comment: Sorry. I added decline to clarify the situation.

Comment: This is not a mathematical cuestión, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A car going down a slope experiences an acceleration of $g \cos{\theta}$, where $g$ is the strength of the near-constant gravitational field on Earth and $\theta$ is the angle of the slope. By integration the car must have a speed of $gt \cos{\theta}$. By integration once more (assuming the car starts with no velocity and at the top of the ramp) the car must be displaced by $\frac{1}{2} gt^2 \cos{\theta}$.

The graph of distance versus time would look like a parabola.

Comment: Eh... In layman's terms? So it accelerates quicker and quicker right?

Comment: If the ramp is a decline, it accelerates because of gravity. You might have heard of it

Comment: The acceleration is constant. The magnitude of the velocity, however, does increase over time, and it increases linearly.

Comment: distance versus time - What do you mean by distance?

Comment: The amount of meters/feet the car travels down the ramp.

Comment: Why would it be a parabola???

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{2}(g \cos{\theta}) t^2$ is the graph of a parabola. How did I get this function? By taking the integral twice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral

Answer (score 0):

If the car starts at rest, but is moving by the end of the ramp, then its speed was not constant.